# SQL Group By that works in SQLite does not work in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

This statement works in SQLite, but not in Postgres:

```
SELECT A.*, B.* 
FROM Readings A 
  LEFT JOIN Offsets B ON A.MeterNum = B.MeterNo AND A.DateTime > B.TimeDate 
WHERE A.MeterNum = 1 
GROUP BY A.DateTime 
ORDER BY A.DateTime DESC
```

The Readings table contains electric submeter readings each with a date stamp.  The Offsets table holds an adjustment that the user enters after a failed meter is replaced with a new one that starts again at zero. Without the Group By statement the query returns a line for each meter reading with each prior adjustment made before the reading date while I only want the last adjustment.

All the docs I've seen on Group By for Postgres indicate I should be including an aggregate function which I don't need and can't use (The Reading column contains the Modbus string returned from the meter).

Comment: Hi, just think, you want a group by A.DateTime, but pg don't know what you want whith the rest of the fields. you must indicate what spec to do with a different rows and the same A.DateTime

Answer (score 0):

Just pick the latest reading in a derived table. In Postgres this can be done quite efficiently using [`distinct on ()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

```
SELECT A.*, B.* 
FROM readings A 
  left join (
     select distinct on (meterno) o.*
     from offsets o
     order by o.meterno, o.timedate desc
  ) B ON A.MeterNum = B.MeterNo AND A.DateTime > B.TimeDate 
WHERE A.meternum = 1 
ORDER BY A.DateTime DESC
```

`distinct on ()` will only return one row per meterno and this is the "latest" row due to the `order by ... , timedate desc`

The query might even be faster by pushing the condition on `datetime > timedate` into the derived table using a [lateral join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL):

```
SELECT A.*, B.* 
FROM readings A 
  left join lateral (
     select distinct on (meterno) o.*
     from offsets o
     where a.datetime > o.timedeate 
     order by o.meterno, o.timedate desc
  ) B ON A.MeterNum = B.MeterNo 
WHERE A.meternum = 1 
ORDER BY A.DateTime DESC
```